# C# WinForms :- Why Thread Timer tick event not elapsed when UI is doing some other operation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

In my application UI, I am updating one of grid through Windows Timer tick every 1 sec.

It's not working properly when I am doing some other UI operations belongs to another windows forms(this is basically using tabbed forms)

I added trace for Timer_Tick event and logged in to file.

We found there is an missing of log data, when another UI operation going on (Open and closing of another windows form). Timer_Tick not hitting at this time.

[image: Log Data trace] 
Any suggestions...?
[image]

Comment: you are missing the screen shot, which makes it very hard to understand what you are talking about

Comment: Timer works properly, it is just your expectations are too optimistic - there is no guarantees that timer will trigger exactly in 1 second, but rather "no earlier than 1 second"...

Comment: So is there no way if we want to display mission critical data updated every one second exactly..

Comment: Sorry Gabriel, I am trying to attach the image but its not working.. Will try to find alternate way to upload it..

Comment: Timers work properly there might be some other reasons?! if you want to check timer create a thread and move your code inside and check CrossThread operations if you are doing UI operations.

Comment: Hi Saeed, I am updating UI from this tick event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the UI is running in a single thread.  Any long-running blocking operation on that thread - like opening a form, running some code in response to a button click, etc - will prevent the timer from firing.  This is the nature of single-threaded programming.

If you absolutely need to run code every second, regardless of what is happening in the UI thread, you'll need to use a second thread.

Related Links:

- [`System.Threading.Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) documentation
- [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) documentation
- [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) documentation

And *very* important, for interacting with your UI from any of the above:

- [`System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) method documentation
- [`System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) property documentation

Comment: Hi Corey, Thanks for the information, regarding the second thread, can you please elaborate more? I want to update UI from the timers tick every 1 sec. Using another Thread will it accurately execute every one sec?

Comment: Yes and no.  You can get *very* accurate timing with a second thread, but any interactions with the main UI thread is going to be affected by blocking operations.  Have a look at the documentation for System.Threading.Timer for a timer that executes on a background thread, and System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke for how to run code in the UI thread from another thread.

Comment: Thanks Corey this is really nice information, I would definitely give a try to Threading.Timer, just one quick question, in the first answer when you talked about using second thread does it mean using Threading.Timer?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do multi-threaded programming - you can create `System.Threading.Thread` objects, `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` objects, use the TPL to handle asynchronous tasks, etc.  `Threading.Timer` is a simple way to do it though, since it handles the threading for you with minimal mess.

Comment: Thanks will try and let you know the result

Answer (score 4):

The `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` tick event executes on the UI thread. If the UI thread is busy doing something else, then the timer tick handler will have to wait.

The tick events for [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) and [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) happen on threadpool threads, so they can execute while the UI thread is busy. If you need to update the UI from your tick handler, you can call [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx), and the UI update will happen when the UI thread is free.

There's no need to start a different thread or a `BackgroundWorker` that executes a `Sleep` loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can run it on a BackgroundWorker since it just happens every 2 seconds without user interaction. For more details about BackgroundWorker, check this article "http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker" it's very easy to understand.

**BackgroundWorker** makes threads easy to implement in Windows Forms. Intensive tasks need to be done on another thread so the UI does not freeze. It is necessary to post messages and update the user interface when the task is done.

Comment: Hi Ronald, I am updating UI every one second, Background Worker thread to my knowledge is Event Driven and would work based on completion of certain activity...

Comment: @Harshal BackgroundWorker can be used in updating every second too.

Comment: Try 

while(true)
{
   // process here
   Thread.Sleep(1000); // mimics one second
}

Comment: NEVER use Thread.Sleep() for timing-sensitive operations such as this.  It is NOT guaranteed to behave as you are expecting it to.  If you need a timer, use one of the built-in .NET constructs meant to be used as such.